# What's an "approximation"?

Tags: calculus

I've started studying taylor series, and my book keeps talking about better "approximating" functions. I don't really understand what they mean.

Given a function $f(x)$ and two other functions $g(x)$ and $h(x)$, how would you determine if $g(x)$ or $h(x)$ is a better "approximation" of $f(x)$.

Essentially I'm asking if a rigourous measure of approximation exists.

Comment: Here is an (admittedly complex, but still quite definitive) example of a function approximating another function.  Note that the "measure" of the approximation is the maximum relative error over the entire complex plane. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/712434/erfaib-error-function-separate-into-real-and-imaginary-part/712568#712568

Comment: It's probably meant in an informal sense.  I would interpret it as meaning, roughly, closer for "more" values of x.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in fact there are many different measures of how 'good' an approximation is; the notion of 'approximation' depends on defining an underlying norm. For instance, let $C[0,1]$ denote the class of continuous real-valued functions defined on the interval $[0,1]$. We may define the *supremum norm* on this space by

$$ \|f\|_{\infty} := sup\{|f(x)| : x \in [0,1]\}.$$

With this norm in hand we can now give a rigorous definition of what 'close' means in this normed space. Picking a very small $\epsilon$ (say 0.0001) we might choose to say that functions $f$ and $g$ $\in C[0,1]$ are 'close' if

$$ \|f-g\|_{\infty} < \epsilon .$$

There are many other function spaces and norms defined on them. Look up, for instance, the $\mathscr{L}^p$ spaces for another example:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space