# Fourier transform of a truncated Gaussian function

Tags: integration, fourier-analysis, gaussian-integral

I am trying to take a Fourier transform of a truncated Gaussian function $f(t,T)=e^{-at^2}I(|t|\leq T)$, where $I(B)$ is the indicator function returning one when boolean variable $B$ is true and zero otherwise.  I thus must solve the following integral:

$$\tilde{f}(\xi,T)=\int_{-T}^Te^{-at^2}e^{-2\pi i \xi t}dt.$$

Wolfram Mathematica "helpfully" returns this "solution" (which can be derived by completing the square):

$$\tilde{f}(\xi,T)=\frac{\sqrt{\pi } e^{-\frac{\pi ^2 \xi^2}{a}} \left(\text{erf}\left(\frac{a T -i\pi  \xi}{\sqrt{a}}\right)+\text{erf}\left(\frac{a T + i\pi  \xi}{\sqrt{a}}\right)\right)}{2 \sqrt{a}}.$$

The symmetrical nature of $f(t,T)$ implies that $\tilde{f}(\xi,T)$ is a real function (this is because a Fourier transform of any even real function is real and even), and thus I am wondering if there is a way to write it without imaginary numbers.  This reduces this writing the following function without the use of imaginary numbers:

$$g(u,v)=\text{erf}(u+iv)+\text{erf}(u-iv),$$

where arguments $u$ and $v$ are real.

However, I am stuck at evaluating erf for complex variables.  I understand that it is possible to do this with complex analysis, but unfortunately, I am not versed in it at all. I thus would be grateful to anyone who could show me how to write the expression for $\tilde{f}(\xi,T)$ without imaginary numbers, and, if possible, carry out the derivation without complex analysis (or stuff simple enough for someone with good background in multivariate calculus and some elementary real analysis).

---

**UPDATE**

I updated the question by somewhat simplifying $\tilde{f}(\xi,T)$, as well as indicating that one can get it by the usual method of completing the square (this was also mentioned in a comment by @tired).  I also made explicit the reason why $\tilde{f}(\xi,T)$ should be a real function.  For clarity, I also adjusted the definition of $g(u,v)$ by using the fact that the error function is odd (i.e., $\operatorname{erf}(x)=-\operatorname{erf}(x)$).  The form of $g(u,v)$ given by @tired in the first comment to this question should be valid.

Also, @tired's point about the conjugate of error function being equal to the error function of the conjugate (that is, $\operatorname{erf}^*(x)= \operatorname{erf}(x^*)$) indeed confirms that $g(u,v)$ is real. This can be shown explicitly as follows:

$$\begin{align}
g(u,v)&=\text{erf}(u+iv)+\text{erf}(u-iv)\\
&=\mathfrak{Re}[\text{erf}(u+iv)]+i\mathfrak{Im}[\text{erf}(u+iv)]+\mathfrak{Re}[\text{erf}(u-iv)]+i\mathfrak{Im}[\text{erf}(u-iv)]\\
&=\mathfrak{Re}[\text{erf}(u+iv)]+i\mathfrak{Im}[\text{erf}(u+iv)]+\mathfrak{Re}[\text{erf}^*(u+iv)]+i\mathfrak{Im}[\text{erf}^*(u+iv)]\\
&=2\mathfrak{Re}[\text{erf}(u+iv)],
\end{align}$$
where $\mathfrak{Re}[a+ib]=a$ and  $\mathfrak{Im}[a+ib]=b$.

Unfortunately, it seems that this is as far as the expression for $\tilde{f}(\xi,T)$ can be simplified, since it is very difficult to analytically separate real and imaginary parts of $\text{erf}(u+iv)$ per [@RonGordon's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/712434/erfaib-error-function-separate-into-real-and-imaginary-part/712568#712568) to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/712434/erfaib-error-function-separate-into-real-and-imaginary-part) (however, good approximation exists per [same answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/712434/erfaib-error-function-separate-into-real-and-imaginary-part/712568#712568)).

Comment: Hint: $erf(z^{*})=erf^{*}(z)$ therefore $g(u,v)=2i\Im erf(ui+v)$ so your original expression is manifestly real. to calculate the integral, just complete the square and use the definition of the error function.

Comment: @tired Thanks for your comment.  I forgot that $\text{erf}(x^*)=\text{erf}^*(x)$.  It doesn't look like an analytical solution exists, but there is a good approximation.  I updated the question with discussion.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/712434/erfaib-error-function-separate-into-real-and-imaginary-part/712568#712568

Comment: @RonGordon Yup, that's the answer to the question that I mention at the end of my update.  I'll put in an explicit link to your answer (which I really enjoyed reading, btw, it's quite a tour de force).

Comment: @M.B.M.: I'm glad you liked it.  I got really interested in that problem a long time ago when I was writing my Ph.D. thesis.  The approximation in A & S is just stunning and I had a lot of fun deriving the expression.  It really is amazing that a computer operating double precision arithmetic would never know the difference between the exact erf of a complex number computed numerically and the approximation.