# Calculate the difference between two error functions with argument having different real parts and same imaginary part

Tags: complex-integration, error-function, gaussian-integral

Does anyone know how to calculate the difference between two error functions with arguments having different real parts and the same imaginary part?

Basically I'm looking to simplify:

$$\mathrm{erf}(L_2 + \mathrm{i} a) - \mathrm{erf}(L_1+\mathrm{i}a).$$

Comment: At first I thought that $\mathrm{erf}(L_2+\mathrm{i}a)-\mathrm{erf}(L_1+\mathrm{i}a)$ could be equal to $\mathrm{erf}(L_2)-\mathrm{erf}(L_1}$ (shifting the integration line on the Real axis), but I think this is wrong.

Comment: I found a previous question that is strictly related to this: [link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1446041/fourier-transform-of-a-truncated-gaussian-function)