# Can Fresnel integrals be expressed as a function of other functions/integrals?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, special-functions, fresnel-integrals

I need to use [Fresnel integrals](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FresnelIntegrals.html) in C++. Is it possible to compute them with any of the [new built-in functions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/special_math) of C++17? or do I have to implement my own solver?

Said otherwise: can Fresnel integrals be expressed as a function of some elliptic integrals (and others, see link above)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Fresnel integrals are related to the Erf function :

http://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/FresnelS/27/01/

http://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/FresnelC/27/01/

and to Hypergeometric1F2 function :

http://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/FresnelS/26/01/01/

http://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/FresnelC/26/01/01/

Comment: The functions he linked to take `double` as an argument type

Comment: :O and erf is in <cmath>! :O thanks!

Comment: @Federico If you are only using real inputs for your Fresnel integrals, it may be slightly more efficient to use:
$$S(x)=\sqrt{\frac\pi2}\Re\left[\frac{1+i}2\operatorname{erf}\left(\frac{1+i}{\sqrt2}x\right)\right]\\C(x)=\sqrt{\frac\pi2}\Im\left[\frac{1+i}2\operatorname{erf}\left(\frac{1+i}{\sqrt2}x\right)\right]$$So only one error function per Fresnel integral.  (note that $\Re(a+bi)=a$ and $\Im(a+bi)=b$)

Comment: For future visitors: I have implemented @SimplyBeautifulArt version given in the comment above with erf(z) computed through the solution given here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/712434/161890 (all other available options, including the series below, degraded in accuracy much faster)

Answer (score 3):

If you wish, you can approach the problems with a [simple series expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresnel_integral#Definition):

$${\displaystyle {\begin{aligned}S(x)&=\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }(-1)^{n}{\frac {x^{4n+3}}{(2n+1)!(4n+3)}}\\[6pt]C(x)&=\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }(-1)^{n}{\frac {x^{4n+1}}{(2n)!(4n+1)}}\end{aligned}}}$$

which follows from Taylor expanding the sines and cosines in the integral definitions.

Comment: Thanks! upvoted for the alternative suggestion, but I am afraid I won't follow it. A series expansion means that I would need to truncate it somewhere, and yes, I could make an investigation on which truncation is enough to fall below machine precision, but if I can avoid it I would prefer it.

Comment: @Federico Well it looks like you've already got that covered :-)