# Sum over recursive sequence with non-constant coefficients

Tags: recurrence-relations, generating-functions, error-function

I wish to find an expression for $\operatorname{Im}\left(\operatorname{erf}\left(u+i\frac{p \pi}{u}\right)\right)$ that I can integrate over $u$ in some more complicated integral, with $p$ a positive integer and $u$ a non-negative real. The general expression
$\operatorname{Im}(\operatorname{erf}(x+iy)) = \frac{\operatorname{erf}(x+iy) - \operatorname{erf}(x-iy)}{2i}$
is unfortunately not helpful for me. I know that such a reformulation is not generally possible, but I'm optimistic since the following equations simplify greatly in the case at hand.

It's easy to show that $$\operatorname{Im}\left(\operatorname{erf}\left(u+i\frac{p \pi}{u}\right)\right) = \frac {2} {\sqrt{\pi}}e^{-u^2} \int_0^\frac{p\pi}{u} e^{t^2} \cos(2ut) dt$$
Looking up the integral in tables always leads back to the original error function, so we use the series expansion of $e^x$:
$$ \int_0^\frac{p\pi}{u} e^{t^2} \cos(2ut) dt = \sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac 1 {n!} \int_0^\frac{p\pi}{u} t^{2n} \cos(2ut) dt = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n$$
Though there is a general solution to the integral, we break it up to apply cancellations due to the parameters. This yields the recursive sequence:
$$a_{n+1} = \frac 1 {2u^2} \left( \frac {\left(\frac{p\pi}u\right)^{2n+1}}{n!} - (2n+1)a_n\right), a_0=0$$
and its explicit form
$$a_n = \frac {(-1)^a} {2 p\pi u} \frac{(2a)!}{2^{2a}a!} \sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k \frac{(2p \pi)^{2k}}{(2k)!}k$$
which is interesting since $\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k \frac{(2p \pi)^{2k}}{(2k)!}k = -p\pi \sin(2p\pi)=0$. (That's how $\lim_\limits{n \to \infty}a_n=0$ despite the factor $\frac{(2a)!}{a!}$, though I couldn't prove that.) I have observed that $a_n > 0$ (again, couldn't prove it).

Unfortunately, neither of those forms allowed me to make progress regarding $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n$. I tried approaching the recursive form using the generating function
$$ A(x)= \sum_{k=0}^\infty a_n x^{2k+1}$$ but $A(x)$ turned out to be (practically) my original error function. I also changed the order of summation in the explicit form, but to no avail.

Can someone suggest a different approach to $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n$? I have tried everything I could come up with, but it never produced something simpler than the above.

Comment: Would you be able to show where you want to integrate this? It might be possible that $\int_{0}^{Q(u)} F(u,t) dt$ is a complicated beast but somehow $\int_{c_0}^{c_1} \int_{0}^{Q(u)} F(u,t) dt du$ is tractable... this type of thing comes up for example in the double integral of volume under a $2D$ gaussian. It doesn't answer your question but hopefully unblocks to keep exploring whatever it is you are working on :)

Comment: @SidharthGhoshal Thank you for the idea. An example of my target integrals would be $\int_0^\infty \left( \frac{1}{u}\exp\left( -\frac{p^2\pi^2}{4u^2} \right)\left[ \operatorname{Im}\left( \operatorname{erf} \left( u- i\frac{p\pi}{2u} \right)\right) + \operatorname{erfi} \left( \frac{p\pi}{2u} \right)  \right] \right)^3 du $. I haven't yet found a way to work on this without first knowing the part I have asked for.

Answer (score 0):

Apologies: this intended comment was too long to submit as such.

I'm not saying that what you wrote down for $\operatorname{Im}(\operatorname{erf}(x+iy)) = \frac{\operatorname{erf}(x+iy) - \operatorname{erf}(x-iy)}{2i}$ is incorrect, but it is not compatible with the published definition for complex error function that I am familiar with. I'm referring to paragraph 7.1.29 in Abramowitz and Stegun, *Handbook of Mathematical Functions*, Dover, 1965. This contains an infinite series. I have programmed this function and used it frequently. It's very complicated and lengthy and would take a very long time just to put it in MathJax format. I suggest that you get this reference. In addition, Table 7.9 has tabulations that you can compare results with.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! I found the given formula at [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1403161/1235501), which cites [this paper](http://dx.doi.org/10.5539/jmr.v7n2). A different answer to that same question explains that paragraph 7.1.29 of the Handbook is only a numerical approximation, not an analytical form. I tried to follow its derivation to get some fortunate simplification into an analytical form in my case, but that didn't work out.